# Make lightning-button-menu work with overflow:hidden

Tags: lightning-web-components, css

Is there a way to prevent that the below lightning-button-menu is hidden by the wrapping div which has an overflow : hidden?

[image]

**buttonMenu.html**

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-p-around_medium overflow-div">
        <lightning-button-menu alternative-text="Show menu">
            <lightning-menu-item value="MenuItemOne" label="Menu Item One"></lightning-menu-item>
            <lightning-menu-item value="MenuItemTwo" label="Menu Item Two"></lightning-menu-item>
            <lightning-menu-item value="MenuItemThree" label="Menu Item Three"></lightning-menu-item>
            <lightning-menu-item value="MenuItemFour" label="Menu Item Four"></lightning-menu-item>
        </lightning-button-menu>
    </div>
</template>
```

**buttonMenu.css**

```
.overflow-div {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: grey;
}
```

Comment: Maybe that helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57223376/lightning-combobox-getting-cut-off

Comment: ...or that one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52684091/lightningoverlaylib-override-overflowhidden-property-to-overflowvisible

Comment: Is there a reason you are adding an overflow: hidden to the parent div? If it's not possible to remove overflow hidden from parent div, maybe try adding position: absolute to lightning-button-menu(you may need to adjust the position in that case

Comment: The reason to add an overflow is I have a container with several divs that can grow dinamically. I want to see an x-scrollball in that container if the screen width is not enough to allocate all the divs inside. The menus are inside of this divs.

Answer (score 0):

At the end, I found a solution: I had to extend the lightning-button-menu component class to add this extra functionality.

Thank you everyone